# How to add a list of strings to a PDF generated with a R script via LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, pdflatex

I have a dataset with survey results where one column can contain comments by the survey participants. If the respondents did not leave a comment, the respective cell is empty. I wrote a R script to generate a PDF with figures and tables showing the results of the survey. As a part of the results I would like to have one page where the before mentioned comments are printed as a list.

I tried the following code to do so:

```
{r, echo=FALSE}
cat(df$comments[!is.na(df$comments)], sep="\n")
```

Basically this code works as intended but unfortunately a comment that is too long exceeds the page margin. Is there any possibility to include a line break in such a case.

Right now I helped myself with a list of the following inline code snippets:

```
`r df$comments[!is.na(df$comments)][1]`
`r df$comments[!is.na(df$comments)][2]`
...etc.
```

In contrary to the first mentioned code, this works fine. Therefore I think that the format of the code chunk is the problem. As the second code only works if I know the number of comments beforehand this is not really a sustainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

This could be something that the chunk option `results` could help with. `results = 'asis'` in a LaTeX document changes the output into LaTeX text rather than a monospaced code block. See [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) for more options.

I'm assuming you are using `.rmd` and pandoc to produce this PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It only helps partially, though. The text now remains within the page margins, but the individual elements are not separated from each other by line breaks like intended with `sep="\n"`. Do you have any idea why that is or how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing the array of comments out as a latex table using one of the readily available table-ing functions in R, e.g. xtable or kable. With kable you can use the 'width' parameter to define the column width and, as a side effect, format the table with the 'p' attribute i.e. text wrapping. For example consider the following minimal Rmd file:

````
---
output:
    output: pdf_document
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{colortbl} 
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(lipsum, kableExtra)
```
```{r}
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(text=replicate(4, lipsum::sentence()))
kable(df, "latex")  %>%
column_spec(., 1, width = "3in")  
```
````

[image: random text comments]